# what is the difference between jquery-1.8.2.js and jquery-1.8.2.min.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i find a topic about difference between  jquery-1.8.2.js and jquery-1.8.2.min.js that is

```
 1. jquery-1.8.2.min.js for  (compressed, for production) 
 2. jquery-1.8.2.js for (uncompressed, for debugging)
```

but I used jquery-1.8.2.min.js for my application, and I am getting an error: `$ is not a function`

If I use both jquery-1.8.2.min.js *and* jquery-1.8.2.js my application is working. Why?

I downloaded .js from http://blog.jquery.com/

Here is the HTML that includes the script on my page:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.ui/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" ></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.ui/jquery-1.8.2.js" ></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.ui/jquery.ui.widget.js" ></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.ui/jquery.ui.core.js" ></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.ui/jquery.ui.menu.js" ></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js" ></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.ui/jquery.ui.position.js" ></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js" ></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.ui/jquery.ui.slider.js" ></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js" ></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery/details.js"></script>
```

in the details.js i using the below code i getting error

```
$('#results_holder').load('test.asp', function() {});
```

Comment: is your site that errors available for us to look at? Is your JQuery tag before your script tag or inline script that is attempting to use JQuery?

Comment: Wait a minute: shouldn't you include `jquery.ui.core.js` before you include `jquery.ui.widget.js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's essentially the same file: `jquery-some-numbers-min-js` is the minified (compressed) version of `jquery-some-numbers-js`. Obviously it makes no sense including it twice.

Comment: but i use any of single file i getting error " $ is not a function "

Comment: then why this error coming when i use single file in my header

Comment: Could you update the question with exact copy of the `<head>` section of your file? In fact, all the script-related lines would suffice.

Comment: <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.ui/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" ></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.ui/jquery-1.8.2.js" ></script>

Comment: You didn't show how your application JS is included. Anyway, does it work when you include `.js` only? Can be a problem with `.min.js` version; could you redownload it?

Comment: -----------------------
$('#cry_').css('background', 'url(../../arrow_down.gif) no-repeat right');

$('#results_holder').load('test.asp', function() {});

Comment: @user475464 The snippet itself is valid, but it doesn't say the slightest bit about how it's related with jQuery includes. Do you include any other JS libraries, or is it just (essentially) `<script src="jquery.js"></script><script>My Script Here</script>`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19371/discussion-between-raina77ow-and-user475464)

Answer (score 2):

In theory they are the same, one is more human readable, the other is compressed to save in load time and bandwidth use.

If you are doing two includes and it works, e.g. :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.ui/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../../jquery.ui/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
```

Then I think including just the second one (non-minified) would work, since it would overwrite the first include.

It's possible there was a bug in the minified version and your app caught it.